# Modify Default URL for /wp-includes/js/wp-emoji.js?ver=4.6.1

Tags: filters, emoji

I need to modify the URL for /wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.6.1 and I have found the following entry that employs the notion of filters:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-default-url-for-new-script-wp-emoji-releaseminjs/

I have included the following code in my functions.php:

```
function filter_my_script_location( $script_url, $script_name ) {
    if ( 'concatemojoi' == $script_name ) {
        $script_url = 'http://mynewdomain/wp-emoji-release.min.js';
    }

    return $script_url;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'filter_my_script_location', 10, 2 );
```

This does not change the Default URL to the one I wanted, is that the correct way to use filters in this case?

Thank you,

P.

**EDIT:**

Also noticed that this caused intermittent 500 errors and only on refresh the page is correctly rendered/loaded.

**EDIT2:**

I must apologise as I have realised that I was actually asking a slightly incorrect thing. I need to modify the URL for /wp-includes/js/wp-emoji.js?ver=4.6.1 The function above was slightly off as kindly pointed out by @birgire, I have amended it as follows:

```
function filter_emojii_location( $script_url, $script_name ) {
    if ( 'concatemoji' == $script_name ) {
        $script_url = 'http://mynewdomain/wp-emoji-release.min.js';
    }

    return $script_url;
}
    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'filter_emojii_location', 10, 2 );
```

Still it has no effect.

Comment: Looks like you've a typo in 'concatemojoi', try 'concatemoji'. Why do you need to modify the wp-embed.js file?

Comment: Hi, thank you for this, well spotted! Unfortunately, the conventional ways for re-directing old domain to new domain did not seem to work for the js libraries, which still have the old domain. I was looking for a workaround.

Comment: So you're migrating a site and the js libraries still point to the old domain? Didn't you change the home and siteurl accordingly like explained [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) ?

Comment: Yes I did, I am afraid.

Comment: That sounds strange, I've migrated many sites but never experienced that. Make sure you changed the correct settings, check e.g. if you have it overriden in wp-config.php. Double check the values in the database. Make sure it's not plugin/theme related. Cache related? Always take a backup of db before modifying during migration..

Comment: Thanks, yes I did each of the task you recommended....

Comment: Did you try [42](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/29402/paranza) ;-) But otherwise I'm not sure what else I can recomend. It seems this might be very localized problem with your site, where one would need to have a full access to it, to be able to work out what the problem is. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have modifed the question as I realised that I was asking about wp-embed.js rather than emojii. Is there a way in the wp-config to set the directory where the js libraries are?

Comment: @birgire how can you effectively check if it is theme related?

Comment: e.g. check if the default theme works without any plugins (take backup first)